# Used OFMT in awk

Tags: shell, ubuntu, awk

I'm reading UNIX Shells by Example / 3th Edition

Example 5.7 in the book

```
nawk 'BEGIN{OFMT="%2.f"; print 1.2456789, 12E-2}'
```

I want to receive:

```
1.25  0.12
```

but I get:

```
1 0
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question. What is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I'm pool at English I want print floating point.

Comment: What output do you expect from the program?

Comment: To learn awk set that book aside and read Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins instead.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use (notice change from `%2.f` to `%.2` - 2 digits after the dot):

```
nawk 'BEGIN{OFMT="%.2f"; print 1.2456789, 12E-2}'
```

If you want to get:

```
1.24 0.12
```

Comment: Sorry, i want to get output 1.24 but i get 1